# ReactDOM is too big when imported

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-dom

How to make ReactDOM smaller when importing into my project?

This is what the Import Cost extension in VS Code shows - it's in read font color - about the size of ReactDOM:

[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHhZV.png)

Any idea how to make it smaller and make Import Costs shows it in green and not red?

Answer (score 0):

ReactDOM is heavy because of the amount of implementations it has. Anyone who uses React will have the same "issue" but I personally wouldn't recommend touching it. This is how it works under the hood if you see anything you want to alter/ remove to make your ReactDOM smaller if it is absolutely necessary.

https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/main/packages/react-dom